# How to read STDERR status using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

This code is not working properly:

```
my_command = %x{java -version &>/dev/null}
 if $? != 0
```

How do I see what the STDERR/STDOUT status code is? 
I tried using `puts`:

```
puts "values ===> $? or or '$?' my_command or #{my_command} %x{echo $?}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Neither STDERR or STDOUT have codes, they're IO streams. `%x`, like backticks, returns whatever was sent to STDOUT by the child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the status code :

```
stdout    = %x(ls -l)
exit_code = $?.exitstatus
```

and then

```
if exit_code == 0 then
  puts "Success"
else
  puts "Problem"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `%x` or something equivalent is an easy way of doing this but doesn't give you a lot of control. Instead use the Open3 library and [`popen3`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3):

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("java", "-version") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  version = stdout.chomp

  status = wait_thr.value
end
```

Comment: `Open3` is very powerful and the tool I reach for when I an writing non-trivial code. `%x` or using backticks are sure convenient for quick and dirty jobs though. :-)